# Unable to notarise .pkg file due to The signature of the binary is invalid and The binary is not signed

Tags: python, swift, macos, security

I'm creating a notarized `.pkg`. I followed few steps to notarization the .pkg file

I use the [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to generate the .pkg file:

[image]

In the Payload tab I added **Python.framework** to **Library** Folder and some files to **/usr/local/** because my application is dependent on the Python framework. So I'm trying to put the Python framework into the end-user system. So I'm directly adding it to the Library folder.

[image]

Now unsigned .pkg file is generated. So using the following [command](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-sign-macos-pkg-files-for-deployment-with-hexnode-mdm/), I create a signed .pkg

```
productsign -sign “Developer ID Installer: Your Apple Account Name (**********)” ~/Desktop/example.pkg ~/Desktop/signed-example.pkg
```

After that, I notarized my signed .pkg with the following command

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "com.xxxxxx.yyyyy” --username “yourmail@xxx.com” --password “app-spefic-password” --file ./singed.pkg
```

when I uploaded my signed .pkg for notarization successfully.

When I check to notarize status with the following command:

```
xcrun altool --notarization-info “request-id(will get after above command successfully)” --username “yourmail@xxx.com” --password “app-specific-password”
```

The package got the invalid status.

When I saw the log file then there are many errors regarding added framework and file:

```
{
  "severity": "error",
  "code": null,
  "path": "Signed.pkg/Signed.pkg Contents/Payload/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python",
  "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.",
  "docUrl": null,
  "architecture": "x86_64"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I have to follow another approach?

Comment: An issue I had codesigning python code was not unzipping zip folders before signing the content of the folder . Another problem I had was I didn’t know you had to target the explicit file names. Her is the link to another answer a stackoverflow user shared that helped me . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679978/code-signing-a-gui-python-app-for-notarization-on-macos